# Facebook Comments on your website via Graph API instead of Comments plugin?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Facebook offers the Comments Plugin for adding comments to any website:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Is it possible to GET and POST comments to your website via the Graph API?

My "URL to comment on" is `http://www.examplesite.com/test/`. If I use the above comments plugin to add a comment to my site, I can access all the comments at the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?id=http://www.examplesite.com/test

Now, is there a way to POST and GET comments to this via the Graph API? I assume my "post id" is `http://www.examplesite.com/test`. I'm trying to use the PHP SDK like so:

```
$params = array( 'message' => 'Hello World!!' );
$facebook->api("http://www.examplesite.com/test/comments", "POST", $params);
```

Also tried to fetch comments as well:

```
$comments = $facebook->api("http://www.examplesite.com/test/comments", "GET");
```

No dice with either of those. Can't post comments or fetch comments.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it not possible to add comments to your site via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about the comment post. but you can get the comments as an assoc array via the API as follows:

```
    $url = 'http://test.com';
    $arr = $this->facebook->api('comments/?ids='.$url); 

    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($arr[$url]['comments']['data']);
```